# PHP: Get current directory index file name

Tags: php, indexing, directory, filenames

I must not be phrasing this question right because I couldn't find an answer to this but surely it's been asked before. How do I get the current filename from a URL if it's the directory's index file?

I.e. This will get index.html if I'm on www.example.com/index.html

```
 $url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

But that won't work if i'm on www.example.com. The only thing I've come up with so far is something like this:

```
 $url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

 if($url == "") {
   $filename = "index.html";
 }
```

But that's obviously a bad solution because I may actually be on index.htm or index.php.  Is there a way to determine this accurately?

Answer (score 2):

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] will determine the full path of the currently executing PHP file. And $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] returns just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the other methods.

```
$url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$urlArray = explode("/",$url));
$urlArray = array_reverse($urlArray);
echo $urlArray[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for "index.html" or whatever the directory index file name is if you're on "www.example.com", and can't see if you're on index.html, index.php, or some other index file.

Comment: $url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `$_SERVER` array entries may not always be available by your server. Some may be omitted, some not. With a little testing though, you can easily find out what your server will output for these entries. On my servers (usually Apache) I find that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` usually gets me the base of the URI I'm after. This also works well for me in the production environment I work on (XAMPP). As my URI will have a localhost root. I have seen people encourage `DOCUMENT_ROOT` before in this situation. You can read all about the `$_SERVER` array [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

In this example, I get the following results:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ; // outputs http://example.com
```

If you are working in a production environment this is very helpful because you won't have to modify your URL's when you go live:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ; // outputs C:/xampp/htdocs/example
```

> 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' The document root directory under which the current
>   script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not trying to get the base of the URI, I'm trying to get the filename if it happens to be the index file name of the directory. For example, if you're on www.example.com, you may be on www.example.com/index.html, or www.example.com/index.php.  I was trying to get the index.html part when it's not visible.

Comment: @John O I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I actually just wrote a function to do just that. `$result = substr( strrchr( $path , "/" ) , 1 ) ) ;` Too bad I already gave an answer.

Comment: `strrchr()` find the last occurrance of a character in a string. in this case `/`. then we just extract the part we want with `substr()`, making sure to not get the `/` by using the optional pointer `1` argument. If you want the slash, just set that parameter to `0`.

Comment: `echo substr( strrchr( "http://example.com/index.html" , "/" ) , 1 ) ) ;` will output `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the last occurrence of the slash `/` using `strrchr()` and simply extract the rest using `substr()`. The optional parameter in `substr()` tells where to begin. With one we skip the slash `/`. If you want to keep it, just set the parameter to `0`.

```
echo substr( strrchr( "http://example.com/index.html" , "/" ) , 1 ) ; // outputs index.html
```

EDIT: Considering that not every server will provide `$_SERVER` with entities, my approach might be more reliable. That is, if the URL you pass to `strrchr()` is reliable. In either case, make sure you test the different outputs from `$_SERVER`, or your paths you provide.